# Counting question about a rectangular block

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the 12 face diagonals of a rectangular block. How many pairs of them are skew lines? (Two lines in space are skew if they do not intersect AND they are not parallel.)

Basically I got that there are $4$ skew lines for every diagonal we take, and there are $12$ diagonals so the answer is just $\dfrac{4 \cdot 12}{2}= \boxed{24}$ but it comes from a source that usually gives hard problems, and this looks REALLY easy.

Is this right?

Comment: Seems to me that there would be $5$ skew lines for each diagonal - one on each of the other faces.

Comment: No because the one on the opposite face is parallel

Comment: Wouldn't only one of the diagonals on the opposite face be parallel?

Comment: Ohhh right... so 5*12/2 = 30?

Comment: Looks good to me.  You could write that up as an answer and then (after a time delay) accept it so the question doesn't stay unanswered.

Comment: I agree with Ross